# What is the limit on the total number of tokens an account can have across all clients in Google OAuth2?

Tags: oauth, google-analytics-api, google-oauth

From the docs on OAuth:

> There is also a larger limit on the total number of tokens a user account or service account can have across all clients. Most normal users won't exceed this limit but a developer's test account might.

see https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration

What is this limit?

I'm asking because we have more than 1000 clients connected with our service account and some users get randomly disconnected (it works fine when the user reconnects their account). Google API responses with the following error:

```
Failed to retrieve access token: {
 "error": "invalid_grant",
 "error_description": "Token has been expired or revoked."
}
```

Note that the user did not disconnect their account in Google setting or anywhere else.

Comment: Check with the users ask them if they have changed their passwords recently.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. We have asked, and not just one user, many users reported the same issue. They insist they didn't change any settings or passwords.

Comment: Service accounts weren't meant to be used like this there's a limit in Google analytics to how many accounts a user can have.  I wonder if this is the problem you are having

Comment: And is meant to be used like this? Users can connect our app with their GA account and we want to create charts and graphs using the data acquired from their account.

Comment: Please include your authentication code.  Also double check that you are updating you refresh token when you request access of the user.   a user can only have 50 outstanding refresh tokens before they stop working